# to concatenate values from excel into a insert query values

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, plsql, excel-formula

I have excel with values in a,b,c,d cells and the 'insert into table values(' in e cell
I want to concatenate all the values as a insert query in f cell.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "insert" cell would be e.g.

```
="insert into test values ('"&A1&B1&C1&D1&"');"
```

Comment: thanks, i tried it, it comes without single quote for each cell values and also first and second cell values comes without space

Comment: each cell value belongs to a tables column value

Comment: i tried to enclose each cell value inside single quote  but getting error,

Comment: Which result (which INSERT statement) do you expect to get? Post an example, e.g. `insert into test values ('abcd')` or ...

Comment: I got the required output as expected based on your input. ="insert into test values ('"&A1&"','"&B1&"');"

Comment: Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Use TRANSPOSE function:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:A20)
```

Select the formula and hit F2 and you will get a long string with a double quote around each record which can later be replaced with a single quote.

`=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:A2000)` if you are using office 365 excel.